# How do I prevent this infinite loop in PowerShell?

Tags: bash, powershell

Say I have several text files that contain the word 'not' and I want to find them and create a file containing the matches.  In Linux, I might do

```
grep -r not *.txt > found_nots.txt
```

This works fine.  In PowerShell, the following echos what I want to the screen

```
get-childitem *.txt -recurse | select-string not
```

However, if I pipe this to a file:

```
get-childitem *.txt -recurse | select-string not > found_nots.txt
```

It runs for ages.  I eventually CTRL-C to exit and take a look at the found_nots.txt file which is truly huge.  It looks as though PowerShell includes the output file as one of the files to search.  Every time it adds more content, it finds more to add.

How can I stop this behavior and make it behave more like the Unix version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-Exclude` option.

```
get-childitem *.txt -Exclude 'found_nots.txt' -recurse | select-string not > found_nots.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

First easy solution is rename file output extension to another

Comment: True but I was hoping not to have such an arbitrary restriction.